# How to access AT command mode on an Xbee Series 2 (Always)

Tags: xbee

I have two working Xbee pro series 2. Configuration went fairly smoothly and they connect on channel 15.

I want them to connect on Channel 11. However when I type "+++" on the terminal window "+++" gets sent to the other xbee module instead of me receiving the "OK" which I sometimes receive. What would be the surefire way to access the AT command config mode? (thanks in advance)

Comment: You need to not send anything for a second, then send just "+++" (no carriage return) and wait another second.  The XBee should come back with "OK" indicating it's in command mode.